# How do I make pdfcrop output all pages of the same size?

Tags: pdf, presentations, pdfcrop, powerpoint

I am trying to crop a powerpoint animation that I converted to pdf for import into beamer (using ppsplit), but when I run `pdfcrop` (from texlive) to reduce the whitespace, it crops the pages individually such that each page is a different size. Is there a way to make it so all pages are the same size as the largest page?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found that the `--verbose` flag will output the bounding box used at each step. Since this was a "growing" animation, the last page is the largest.

So to get them all the same size, I ran pdfcrop with --verbose and extracted this output:

```
%%HiResBoundingBox: 48.000022 299.872046 624.124950 420.127932
```

and then fed that to a second run of pdfcrop, specifying the bounding box:

```
pdfcrop --bbox "48.000022 299.872046 624.124950 420.127932" ~/animation.pdf
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `sh` shell function to crop all pdf pages to the same size. The function depends on `pdfcrop` and GNU `datamash`, so make sure to install them.

```
pdfconstcrop() {
    pdfcrop --bbox "$(
        pdfcrop --verbose "$@" |
        grep '^%%HiResBoundingBox: ' |
        cut -d' ' -f2- |
        LC_ALL=C datamash -t' ' min 1 min 2 max 3 max 4
    )" "$@"
}
```

Copy-paste above code block into your terminal and then simply use `pdfconstcrop` instead of `pdfcrop`. The usual `pdfcrop` options still work. Some examples:

- **`pdfconstcrop in.pdf`** writes result to `in-crop.pdf`.
- **`pdfconstcrop in.pdf out.pdf`** writes the result to `out.pdf`
- **`pdfconstcrop --margins 50 in.pdf`** leaves (at least) 50pt margins at each side.

Comment: This solution will not work if the locale of your machine uses comma as the decimal separator. To make sure that datamash works, set the locale to C:

```
pdfconstcrop() {                                                                 [130]
    pdfcrop --bbox "$(
        pdfcrop --verbose "$@" |
        grep '^%%HiResBoundingBox: ' |
        cut -d' ' -f2- |
        LC_ALL=C datamash -t' ' min 1 min 2 max 3 max 4 
    )" "$@"
}
```

Comment: @vlopez Thank you for your valuable comment. I incorporated your suggestion into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the last page is not the largest, we need to compute the maximum width and height among all the pages, and then use these values to determine the right bounding boxes. Note that the four coordinates in a bounding box are:

- x-coordinate (distance from left edge of page) of upper-left corner,
- y-coordinate (distance from top edge of page) of upper-left corner,
- x-coordinate (distance from left edge of page) of bottom-right corner,
- y-coordinate (distance from top edge of page) of bottom-right corner.

Computing the right bounding boxes for each page and using them could be done with an appropriate patch to the `pdfcrop` script (it's written in Perl), but as I'm not very comfortable with Perl, did it in Python instead; here is the script in case it's useful to someone.

```python
import re, sys
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
width = height = 0
# First pass: compute |width| and |height|.
for line in lines:
  m = re.match(r'\\page (\d*) \[([0-9.]*) ([0-9.]*) ([0-9.]*) ([0-9.]*)\](.*)', line, re.DOTALL)
  if m:
    page, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, rest = m.groups()
    width = max(width, float(xmax) - float(xmin))
    height = max(height, float(ymax) - float(ymin))
# Second pass: change bounding boxes to have width |width| and height |height|.
for line in lines:
  m = re.match(r'\\page (\d*) \[([0-9.]*) ([0-9.]*) ([0-9.]*) ([0-9.]*)\](.*)', line, re.DOTALL)
  if m:
    page, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, rest = m.groups()
    xmin = float(xmin)
    ymin = float(ymin)
    xmax = float(xmax)
    ymax = float(ymax)
    # We want |xmin| and |xmax| such that their difference is |width|
    addx = (width - (xmax - xmin)) / 2.0
    xmin -= addx
    xmax += addx
    # We want |ymin| and |ymax| such that their difference is |height|
    addy = (height - (ymax - ymin)) / 2.0
    ymin -= addy
    ymax += addy
    sys.stdout.write(r'\page %s [%s %s %s %s]%s' % (page, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, rest))
  else:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Usage:

1. Run the regular `pdfcrop` command, with `--debug`, e.g.:

   ```
   pdfcrop --debug foo.pdf
   ```

   Because of `--debug`, it will not delete the `tmp-pdfcrop-*.tex` file it created.
   Also, note down the `pdftex` (or whatever) command it executed at the end, if you had passed in some special options to `pdfcrop` and it's therefore nontrivial.
2. Pass the `tmp-pdfcrop-*` file through the script above, e.g.:

   ```
   python find-common.py < tmp-pdfcrop-34423.tex > tmp-pdfcrop-common.tex
   ```

   This will write out `tmp-pdfcrop-common.tex` with different bounding boxes.
3. Run the `pdftex` (or whatever) command that `pdfcrop` called, with this file:

   ```
   pdftex -no-shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode tmp-pdfcrop-common.tex
   ```
4. Check the resulting PDF file, and rename it to whatever you like:

   ```
   mv tmp-pdfcrop-common.pdf foo-crop.pdf
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python package that I think fits the asked question ideally: https://github.com/abarker/pdfCropMargins

For example the command:

```
$ pdf-crop-margins -u -s in.pdf
```

crops `in.pdf` so that all the pages are set to the same size and the cropping amount is uniform across all the pages retaining by default 10% of the existing margins is used. The output file is approximately of the same size as the input file and links, annotations are preserved as well.