# Position includepdf to top of page (when input is of varied size)

Tags: positioning, pdfpages

I'm trying to include a pdf document into my main LaTeX document (all my publications into my manuscript), but I want to keep the same page numbering throughout. I'm using the **pdfpages** package as follows,

```
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}

\includepdf[pages={-}, % all pages
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}} % continue page numbering
]{file.pdf}
```

For most files this works great, but for one particular file this happens:

[image: Input doesn't fit, trails off the page]

Definitely not what I wanted, so I removed all excess margins by applying

```
 pdfcrop file.pdf file-pdfcrop.pdf
```

And update the options as follows,

```
\includepdf[pages={-}, % all pages
width=\textwidth, % full text-width
frame=true, % for debugging
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}} % continue page numbering
]{file-pdfcrop.pdf}
```

This works fine but not exactly aesthetically pleasing for some pages. As the pages in file.pdf have been cropped to various sizes.
[image: Input fits, but centered]

Is there any way to force \includepdf to be positioned to the top of the page instead of the default centering?

PS This is my first post on tex.stackexchange, so be gentle ;-)

Comment: if it's only one page you can try include it as figure with option `[t]` but i think it's better if you solve your first problem without croping the pdf file

Comment: Each file is several pages, and usually it's the references (last page) that gets all messed up (see pic). I'm doing this for all of my publications, so I'm hoping for _magic_ formula that works on all files the same. Especially since my original files were published on various formats.

Comment: Hope there is a better solution now?

Answer (score 2):

I figured I might as well just use [pdfcrop to same sized margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166758/how-do-i-make-pdfcrop-output-all-pages-of-the-same-size/166759#166759) and using a bash script to apply it to all of my pdfs

```
for file in $DIRECTORY/*.pdf; do
  # Process $file
  echo $file
  # Find bounding boxes
  pdfcrop --verbose $file tmp.pdf | grep "%%HiResBoundingBox:" > bbox; 
  # First page has the largest bounding box
  largest=`echo $(head -n 1 bbox)| cut -d':' -f 2` 
  # Crop $file
  pdfcrop $file tmp.pdf --bbox "$largest"
  mv tmp.pdf $file
done
rm bbox
```

Finally, success! [image: Final result]

Comment: Did you find a LaTex solution for this?

Comment: Nope. I remember finding only solutions for 1-page pdfs. Which didn't solve my particular problem. Once I found a good-enough workaround I was happy, although I'd have preferred a built-in LaTeX solution so I wouldn't need to keep an extra copy of the included files without margins.

Comment: Hope there is a better solution now?

Answer (score 0):

As the OP and CasperYC have also asked for a solution to include pages at the *top* of each page, here is one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1-}, scale=0.75, offset=0 180]{mySlides.pdf}% play with the offset parameter (shifting pages to the right/top)
\end{document}
```

See the documentation [here](https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) for more details. Perhaps this would need to be called for specific pages only as otherwise all pages are offset.